# Why does this keep turning out as Payroll, not Employees, even if I say employees?

Tags: c++

So, will first log in, then I will chose Employees, but it always gives me payroll. I don't know if I messed up code-wise or it's just the stupid Online IDE I'm using. Well, here it is...

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#ifndef en
#define en std::endl
#endif

using namespace std;

void login() {
    //Basic login program
    string correctPass = "Love";
    string attemptPass;
    cout << "Please insert password" << en;
    cin >> attemptPass;
    if (attemptPass == correctPass) {
        cout << "Access Granted" << en << en;
    } else {
        login();
    }
}

void mainMenu() {
    void employees();
    void payroll();
    cout << en << "MAIN MENU" << en << en << "Payroll" << en << "Employees" << en << en;
    string mainMenuOption;
    cin >> mainMenuOption;
    if (mainMenuOption == "Payroll" || "payroll") {
    payroll(); }
    else if (mainMenuOption == "Employees" || "employees") {
    employees(); }
    else {
    mainMenu(); }
}

void payroll(){
    cout << en << "WELCOME TO PAYROLL" << en << "-----------------" << en << "fish" << en;
}

void employees(){
    cout << en << "WELCOME TO EMPLOYEES" << en << "-----------------" << en << "eleven" << en;
}

int main() {
    login();
    mainMenu();

    return 0;
}
```

If anyone know's how I messed up please tell! Thanks!

Comment: Your usage of `||` is wrong.

Comment: `mainMenuOption == "Payroll" || "payroll"` => `mainMenuOption == "Payroll" || mainMenuOption == "payroll"`

Comment: Should be `int main`

Comment: Thanks! I'm really bad at this currently, and am sorry for taking up your time, and am very thankful for helping me with these little things like this that make no sense unless you really have been doing this for a while!

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings and let the compiler tell you about silly mistakes like this.

Comment: In your main menu. This function call is wrong `void payroll();` the correct is just `payroll();` also for `employees();`

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in the comments. Your comparison is not quite right.

Advice: Don't use `using namespace std` see why here: [Why is “using namespace std” in C++ considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-in-c-considered-bad-practice). Also use `\n` instead of `std::endl` for better performance unless you really want the advantages of `std::endl` (like flush()).

Also your function call should not include the return type. To call `payroll()` you just use `payroll();` and not `void payroll();`

This should work:

```
# include <iostream>
# include <string>
# ifndef en
#define en std::endl
#endif

void login()
{
    //Basic login program
    std::string correctPass = "Love";
    std::string attemptPass;

    std::cout << "Please insert password:\n";
    std::cin >> attemptPass;

    if (attemptPass == correctPass)
        std::cout << "Access Granted\n\n";
    else
        login();
}

void mainMenu()
{
    employees();
    payroll();

    std::cout << "\nMAIN MENU\n\nPayroll\nEmployees\n\n";
    std::string mainMenuOption;
    std::cin >> mainMenuOption;

    if (mainMenuOption == "Payroll" || mainMenuOption == "payroll")
        payroll();
    else if (mainMenuOption == "Employees" || mainMenuOption == "employees")
            employees();
         else
            mainMenu();
}

void payroll()
{
    std::cout << "\nWELCOME TO PAYROLL\n-----------------\nfish\n";
}

void employees()
{
    std::cout << "\nWELCOME TO EMPLOYEES\n-----------------\neleven\n";
}

int main()
{
    login();
    mainMenu();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Better fix indentation while you're at it.

Comment: you are wrong about the function calls; Those are in fact forward declarations in an unusual place

Comment: @pm right I thought about prototypes but I am not sure what he means with it